# Retrieving Windows files with USB adapter; Linux install wiped out Windows

Tags: adapter

So long story short, I was told by other members on this forum that I completely wiped out windows while installing ubuntu, on my computer.

Now, I would like to retrive as many windows files/docs/photos as possible.

One of the options suggested was to use a USB to harddrive adapter.

I removed my harddrive and hooked it up to an adapter I got from Amazon.

Can someone please tell me where do I go from here? How do I use the adapter to retrive as many windows files as possible? ( I have a second laptop that has windows and Linux on it. It will be used to conduct the rescue mission )

Thank you

Comment: you will need software to scan the drive here is a link with how to (https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-formatted-partition.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The first action you should perform is to make a bit-for-bit copy of all the data. Any further processing should be done on this copy, in order to prevent further data loss.

The `dd` command is ideal for this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdb of=my_harddrive.img bs=1024
```

This will copy every bit of the harddrive `/dev/sdb` into the file named `harddrive.img`, copying 1024 bytes at a time. It will take a *long* time. Make sure you have plenty of disk space to save the file.

Now that you have your backup file, there are many ways to attempt data recovery. Personally, I'm a fan of [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which, despite its name, can recover much more than just photos.

```
$ photorec my_harddrive.img
```

Good luck!

Comment: keep in mind however this isn't a guarantee to recover your data - if Linux overwrote Windows it's impossible to know how much data you'll actually be able to recover because there's data that's been replaced on disk and won't be recoverable.